# Creating n number of masked subarrays for all the n unique values in an array using python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array created from a raster. This array has multiple unique values. I want to create new arrays for each unique value such that the places with that value are marked as '1' and the rest as '0'. I am using python for this.

```
A = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3] # Input array
b = numpy.unique(A) # gives unique values
a1 = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0] #new array for value 1
a2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] #new array for value 2
a3 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1] #new array for value 3
```

So basically the code would scan through the unique values, get the number of unique values and create individual arrays for each unique value.

I have used the `numpy.unique()` and `numpy.zeros()` to get the unique values in the array, and to create arrays that can be overwritten to the desired array, respectively. But I do not how to get the code to get the number of unique values and create that many new arrays.

I have been trying to do this with the `for loop`, but I haven't been successful. My concepts of developing such a nested `for loop`are not very clear yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> A = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3]
>>> result = [(A==unique_val).astype(int) for unique_val in np.unique(A)]

[array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])]
```

The core part of the program being:

`(A == unique_val).astype(int)`

It's simply comparing the elements in numpy array with `unique_val`, each element return a `boolean` result. By using `astype(int)` we are converting the boolean result to an integer array.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. And it is very well explained. Is there any documentation to refer to to clear these basic  concepts?

Comment: Is it possible to save each array in the result variable as an individual variable? That can be called later for other calculations, like counting number of values that overlap with other arrays?

Comment: @B_123 You can create a dictionary instead of a list with the key being the unique_value.

Comment: I tried this
dc_ ={}
for i in Auniq:
    for j in result:
        dc_ = {i: j}
        print(dc_)

The result was as below
{1: array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])}
{1: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])}
{1: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])}
{2: array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])}
{2: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])}
{2: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])}
{3: array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])}
{3: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])}
{3: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])}

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
a1 = (A == b[0]) * 1
```

And, instead of b[0], create a loop using len(b) and  iterate with b[i].

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to do is with broadcasting:

```
locs = (A[None, :] == b[:, None]).astype(int)
out = {val: arr for val, arr in zip(list(b), list(locs))}
```

Comment: I am getting error - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: Make sure all your lists are converted to `numpy` arrays first using `np.array(A)`.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works, but is it possible to save each array in the resulting list as an individual variable, for each unique value? That can be called later for other calculations, like counting number of values that overlap with other arrays? I have tried making a dictionary based on hashcode55's suggestion above. But I got 9 arrays (See my comment to hashcode55's answer). I am surely missing something obvious. It would be nice if you could please help.

Comment: `out = {val: arr for val, arr in zip(list(b), list(A))}` ?

Comment: When I run this in the QGIS python console I get the error - TypeError: 'zip' object is not callable. I have trying to use the zip function for a long time but it just doesn't work; can't seem to figure out why. In Spyder I get the output: {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3}  Is there an alternative to the zip function

Comment: Think you really need another question at this point.  I'm lost.

Comment: Please see the revised question at the new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57176512/count-of-the-number-of-identical-values-in-two-arrays-for-all-the-unique-values